# How can I compute the angle between $f(x)=3x^2+2$ and $g(x)=2x+3$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Compute the angle between the vectors: $$f(x)=3x^2+2 \\g(x)=2x+3$$

Using the standard dot product: $a \cdot b=\lvert a \rvert \lvert b\rvert \cos{\alpha} \iff \alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a \cdot b}{\lvert a \rvert \lvert b\rvert }\right)$.

The dot product of two functions is defined as: $<a\vert b>=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$

Calculation:

$\lvert f \rvert=<f\vert f>=\int_a^bf^2dx=\int_a^b (3x^2+2)^2 dx=\frac{9}{5}b^5+4b^3+4b-\frac{9}{5}a^5-4a^3-4a :=\Delta$

$\lvert g\rvert=>g \vert g>=\int_a^bg^2 dx=\int_a^b(2x+3)^2dx=\frac{4}{3}b^3+6b^2+9b-\frac{4}{3}a^3-6a^2-9a :=\Gamma$

$<f \vert g>=\int_a^bfgdx=\int_a^b (3x^2+2)(2x+3)dx=\frac{3}{2}b^4+3b^3+2b^2+6b-\frac{3}{2}a^4-3a^3-2a^2-6a:=\Theta$

$$\implies\alpha=\arccos{\frac{\Theta}{\Delta \Gamma}}$$

Should I be be getting an actual angle or is this result correct? I thought about looking at the intersections between the two functions and then changing $a$ and $b$ to intervals containing the intersection. Would that be a possible solution?

Comment: I think angle is $0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Can you maybe give me an explanation?

Comment: First of all am I right

Comment: @ArchisWelankar If the answer was zero then the functions would have to be orthogonal. I don't think they are (at least from a geometric perspective).

Comment: No we see the angle between tangents of function as a second degree curves can't make an angle so it's $dy/dx$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar So the angle I am looking for is the angle between the tangents, i.e. the angle between $g'(x)=2$ and $f'(x)=6x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake. $$|f|=\sqrt{(\langle f|f\rangle)}.$$

Angle depends on the definition of inner/dot product. You have to define the inner product first (i.e. including fixing your $a$ and $b$, different $a$ and $b$ will give you different angle) before computing its angle.It has nothing to do with intersection point.

Comment: Thank you. There was no $a$ and $b$ given. Is the question incomplete?

Comment: Well, perhaps you can leave the answer in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes I am going to leave the answer in terms of a and b I think. Thanks for your help!